# Initializing OLEObject to return default value

Tags: excel, vba, activex

I have a workbook set up with ActiveX checkboxes that return a "Yes" or "No" answer to cells in corresponding workbooks. When the checkboxes are clicked, they return a "no" answer as desired and will return "yes" if then clicked again to de-check it. But they return nothing upon opening of the workbook, which I understand is because they need the `_Click` event to occur first. What I want is for these objects to return a default "Yes" value if the user does not click them. I'm guessing I have to write something in the `Private Sub Workbook_Open()` procedure, but I'm not sure what to write in it.

```
Private Sub FilteredBox1_Click()


'If FilteredBox1 clicked, evaluates to True and passes "Yes" to Module1.FilBox. Otherwise passes "No".
If FilteredBox1.Value = True Then
    Module1.FilBox = "No"
ElseIf FilteredBox1.Value = False Then
    Module1.FilBox = "Yes"
Else
    Module1.FilBox = "True"
End If

'Saves entered Boolean value of OLEObject to string form
wbSAR.Worksheets("COC Form").Range("B46").Value = Module1.FilBox
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a satisfactory solution that was very simple. Rather than dealing with the OLEobjects, I just went into the `Workbook_Open()` procedure and set the initial value of the output variables to "Yes".